# How to kill a javascript redirect if button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, redirect, kill

I have come up with the following code, which allows users to view a page with a movie embed for 30 seconds before redirecting them away from the page. Additionally, they can click a link to hide the div with this countdown. What I need help with is canceling the redirect (stopping it from happening) if that link is clicked, so users can continue to watch the full movie. Thanks in advance for your help!

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var settimmer = 0;
    $(function(){
            window.setInterval(function() {
                var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
                var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
                $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);


                if(updateTime == 0){
                    window.location = ("redirect.php");
                }
            }, 1000);

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").show();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my-timer" class="slidingDiv">
    You have <b id="show-time">30</b> seconds to decide on this movie.
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Yes, I want to watch this one!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a value you can use to cancel the interval timer via `clearInterval`. So:

```
$(function(){
        //  +--- Remember the value from `setInterval
        //  |
        //  v
        var timerHandle = window.setInterval(function() {
            var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
            var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
            $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);


            if(updateTime == 0){
                window.location = ("redirect.php");
            }
        }, 1000);

        // + Hook up a handler for the link that uses the handle to clear it
        // |
        // v
        $("selector_for_the_link").click(function() {
            clearInterval(timerHandle);
            timerHandle = 0;
        });
});
```

Note that I've put the variable *inside* your `ready` function, so it isn't a global.

---

**Off-topic**: You don't need or want to use `eval` in the above (in fact, you virtually never want to use `eval` at all, for anything). If you want to parse a string to make a number, use `parseInt` (and there's never any reason to eval a literal like `1`). So this line:

```
var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
```

becomes

```
var updateTime = parseInt(timeCounter, 10) - 1;
```

(The `10` means the string is in decimal — e.g., base 10.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I implemented all your suggestions and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [setTimeout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to do so rather than setInterval().Here is a [sample](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/setTimeout.htm).